# setState in while loop causing "Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop"

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to calculate countDiff and add the object to the record array countDiff times. For example, if countDiff value is two then I would like to add two same objects with incremented tempRecordId.

However "Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop" error came up. Do you know any way to setState in a loop or the way to figure out this logic?

```
      const countDiff = homeRecordCount - awayRecordCount;

      let i = 0;
      let insertTeamId = countDiff > 0 ? awayTeamId : homeTeamId;

      if (countDiff != 0)
      {
        while(countDiff != i)
        {
          setTempRecordId(tempRecordId + 1);
          addRowToRecord({scoreMemberName:null, scoreMemberId: null, scoreTeamId: insertTeamId, assistMemberName: null, assistMemberId: null, matchId: matchId, codeId: 7, id: 0, tempRecordId: tempRecordId })
      i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, a tip: if you run into more issues I find that while loops aren't always suitable for web because they are blocking (the next line can't run until it's done), and often what you want is a Promise or async/await. It seems fine in this case, just wanted to pass that along :)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use conditionals nor loops in your Hook component. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

In this case you could just add all the records at once.

Comment: Conditional are fine for setting state, just not declaring state.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this situation is to construct the final object you need before you ever set state in the first place ie move your set state to after the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

It means once you call to setState then it will render your page. your logic set to never ending loop . I guess All the time (countDiff != i = > true)comes to inside of the while loop. Please set your logic with some ending condition.